# My renders keep coming out all black despite having lights

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to render a scene using cycles inside of a cave model. I have the camera and the lights set up (I believe it is done correctly?). I have also tried rendering with global illumination, and still, I just get a black square.

To be clear, I want to render the inside, and there are already two point lights inside, near the camera that I believe are configured correctly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing your lamp strength a lot (click use nodes).

[image: use_nodes]

[image: viewport_render]

Comment: You beat me to it!!! xD

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I have never used the `use nodes` for my lamps. I also did not know lamp strength could go to those high of numbers!

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is your camera is positioned inside one of your walls! Move it out a little bit, and you should get the render you want.

I'm assuming the maze is the outer part, like a labyrinth cave thing, but if it's supposed to be on the inside, then what you need to do is add lamps inside, too. If the light can't reach the camera, nothing will show up.

**EDIT (new information):**

I've messed around with your file, and the issue seems to be something to do with your lamps. I can't figure out what's wrong with them, but the scene rendered properly when I simply added a new point lamp, at default values. Try replacing your lamps.

Comment: Sorry, that is something I should have stated in my question, I want to render the inside, and there are already two point lights inside , near the camera, as well.

Comment: I'll have another look, then, I missed the other point lights.